# Detaching LCD cable from motherboard

Tags: motherboard, laptop-display, lenovo-laptop

How do I detach LCD cable from motherboard (lenovo B560)?

Link is to my drive where I posted close-up pictures of it:

https://drive.google.com/folder/d/0By5Sw6G6VsXLcnNTTG9pazB0d2M/edit

Been stuck at it for a couple of days, too frighten of forcing it out when I don't know how.

Thanks upfront!

Comment: that called "Ribbon Cable", you can do a search like  "how to remove Ribbon Cable"

Comment: I used "ribbon cable" as I used "LCD cable" in Google search but nothing came out of it and this is my last resort. I don't even know is this metal connector removable together as the ribbon or should the ribbon come out without any attachments.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It is hard to tell for sure from the pictures, but that may be a zero insertion force (link below) type connector. If that is the case, the metal bracket will stay right where it is and you will need to release the latch that is holding the ribbon's exposed conductors to those on the PCB. Once you do that, you should be able to slide it right out. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_insertion_force

Comment: Here's another link that you'll probably find helpful: https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Recognizing+%26+Disconnecting+Cable+Connectors/25629

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That metal wire thing is a handle.  You can just pull it up.  It should not take too much force.  In other words, it looks like the connector pulls straight up off of the motherboard.  I've seen these plenty of times.  If in doubt, though, you should not have to force it too much, just apply firm and steady pressure as you pull it and it will pop off.

Comment: Yes that was it. I tried editing my question but nothing happened, so thanks for realy fast answer(s).